# New Wordpress WP Query using posts from certain categories

Tags: wp-query, query

I want to display the last say 6 pieces of work from my portfolio. So i have written this query

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query array( 'category_name' => 'portfolio', 'showposts=6' ); ?>

<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Can someone advise if im missing something as it doesnt seem to be working.
thanks

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query array( 'category_name' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 6, ); ?>
```

This now comes up with a T Array error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code, you have to change:

- `$the_query -> have_posts()` to `$the_query->have_posts()`
- `$the_query -> the_post()` to `$the_query->the_post()`
- `WP_Query array(...)` to `WP_Query(array(...))`
- `'showposts=6'` to `'posts_per_page' => 6`

Try this instead

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) ); 
while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); 
    the_post_thumbnail(); 
endwhile;
```

Comment: Hi Bigire, thankyou so much for that assistance :)

Comment: Hi there, This completely wiped everything :S....now no image or text unlike my first query that was showing this

Comment: Hi Kirsty, remember to change `WP_Query array(...)` to `WP_Query(array(...))`, otherwise you will get a PHP parse error.

Comment: Hi Birgire, I did this and it still didnt work :S

Comment: actually think i know why XD

Comment: help if i had something in the portfolio category to post.. wouldnt it.. XD.. thankyou both xx

Comment: Birgire, are you on chat, i just have a quick question :)

Comment: sure, can you create a chatroom?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the enclosing brackets when you instantiate the new WP_Query class! It should be `$the_query = new WP_Query( array('category_name' => 'portfolio', ... ) );`

See the usage section of the documentation for [Class_Reference/WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage) on the WordPress codex for more information, and [birgire's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101920/10789) for the correct code solution!

Also please note that the arguments array passed in to the class is in an *associative* structure and requires the [appropriate syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (e.g. `array( 'arg_name_1' => 'arg_val_1', arg_name_2' => 2 );`

In this particular case though I also think that 'showposts' is incorrect, you should be using the 'posts_per_page' argument (e.g. `'posts_per_page' => 6`) -- see the source file reference on the [gist.github page](https://gist.github.com/luetkemj/2023628)

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for this, sorry first time at writing queries so im sketchy XD

Comment: Hey no worries, (sorry) mine was a bit of a sketchy answer ;) -- at least between you me and the awesome Mr @birgire here we should have your problem all straightened out!

Comment: <?php $the_query = new WP_Query array( 'category_name' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 6, ); ?> this came up with a T Array error?

Comment: Still missing the WP_Query enclosing brackets!! -- new WP_Query( array( ... ) ); ... seriously @birgire got it right on the nose for you, but hopefully the reference links I provided should offer some more insight and clarity... if you study them! XD

Comment: there needs to be more user friendly dumb tutorials for people like me on wordpress lol!